# Story about Nachman of Breslov on the holiness of Eretz Yisrael

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, breslov, hasidic-story

I heard a story (I think it was recorded by Reb Noson) about either a Shabbes of Yomtov when Rabbi Nachman of Breslov was sick, and many students came to visit him. He was too weak to deliver an address, but towards the end of the yomtov, partly due to his distress, he summons an enormous amount of energy and delivers a very long and impassioned speech about the holiness of Eretz Yisrael and how we are able to imbue it into the land in which we reside.

Does anybody recognise the story or have a source for it?

Comment: Rebbe Nachman gave maimarim?? This sounds like a Lubavitch story to me.

Comment: @ShimonbM Rav Hutner gave mamarim does that make him a lubavitcher?

Comment: Consider dejargonfying, e.g. Shabbes, maimar. Not everyone has the same level of background and the site is meant to accomedate those who only speak English as well.

Comment: Not giving an opinion of whether maimar is jargon that needs to be explained, but surely on this site, Shabbes is not "jargon," it is a fundamental that everybody who belongs here will understand.  Even an Israeli who pronounces it "Shabbot."

Comment: @MarkFischler mevaqesh This is the site policy on jargon usage http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1607/759 Arguably only common spelling variants are included in the "commonly found in English" category.

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv - I stand corrected, thank you. I did not know that.

Comment: As an aside, Rebbe Nachman spoke _extensively_ on kedushas Eretz Yisroel. He was exceedingly passionate about Eretz Yisroel throughout his life.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, sorry for bothering everyone. The content is Likutei Moharan Tanina 78 and the story is Sichot Haran 153.

Comment: Shalom, thanks for coming back and sharing your findings with everyone

Comment: Awesome for finding the answer! And no worries about answering your own question, I did the same thing here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75328/commonly-used-breslov-siddur